# Using Jquery to enlarge images on mouseover without moving others

Tags: jquery, hover, image-enlarge

I'm trying to make a toolbar where each image enlarges when you hover over it.  However, I want only the icon you're on to be the one that moves.  As my code is now, the whole line shifts.

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
     $('.socialmediaBar img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: "+=2%", height: "+=20%" });
});

$('.socialmediaBar img').mouseleave(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('width'),
        y = $(this).attr('height');

    $(this).stop().animate({ width: x, height: y });
});
```

This is the css:

```
.socialmediaBar{
    height:30px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.socialmediaBar img{
    position: static;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height:30px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.socialmediaBar a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="socialmediaBar">

        <a href="mailto:jrossbeitzel@gmail.com"><img src="Images/Icons/envelope.png" height="30" width="30"/> </a> 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ross.beitzel" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Icons/facebook.png" height="30" width="30" /> </a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/jrossbeitzel" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Icons/twitter.png" height="30" width="30" /> </a>    
        <a href="https://vimeo.com/user35376371" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Icons/Vimeo.png" height="30" width="30" /> </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jamesrossbeitzel" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Icons/linkedin.png" height="30" width="30" /> </a>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

You could set a container for the images:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="mailto:jrossbeitzel@gmail.com">
        <img src="Images/Icons/envelope.png" height="30" width="30"/>
    </a> 
</div>
```

The container must have a static height and width:

```
.socialmediaBar .container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j89b06es/2/). It breaks your toolbar styles a bit, but there should be no problem fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the links fixed size `inline-block`s and the images inside `absolute`.

```
.socialmediaBar a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 18px;
}

.socialmediaBar img {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/b3be5rve/).

And here is my second [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/b3be5rve/2/), for upwards animation. Note: this could be done with css transitions too. Try to delete the whole javascript code, and uncomment the two comments in the css.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried it out this way and worked like a charm.  The icons animate down and to the right a bit though.  Do you have any advice on how to make them go straight up instead?

Comment: I added a second jsfiddle.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks so much for the help!  I tweaked it a bit and it worked like a charm.  When it went up it stretched so I added some width, but when I did that it made it move to right again (but everything else stayed in place so that was good).  What I ended up doing was changing the CSS style and took out the height/width and added padding to the bottom so when hovered, instead of growing and moving it just moved up.  This'll work great!  Thanks so much for helping me through it!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer, if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: I definitely would but it won't let me since I don't have enough reputation :-/  If there's another way to give you cred just lemme know.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's ok. :)